# C -writing and reading from sockets

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I have to send two bytes using a tcp socket in c.

My try so far:

```
static void send_request(int sockfd) {
    uint8_t buffer[SEND_BYTES];
    uint8_t requestLowByte = 0;
    uint8_t requestHighByte = 0;

.... calculating the values for the two bytes

    bzero(buffer,SEND_BYTES);
    buffer[0] = requestLowByte;
    buffer[1] = requestHighByte;

    connfd = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    if (connfd < 0) {
        bail_out(EXIT_FAILURE, "ERROR writing to socket\n", progname);
    }
}
```

my testing values: 
I tried to send the values 248 and 127 in a loop to the server. 
On the server-side I received: 248 127, 7 248, 127 7, 7 7,7 7, 248 127 ... Where do the extra values come from?

Thanks in advance for your answers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
connfd = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
```

Should be:

```
connfd = write(sockfd, buffer, SEND_BYTES);
```

`strlen` function is looking for a `\0` to compute the length of the buffer, and since you don't make sure there is a `\0` after the second value in the array to send, it's undefined behaviour there.

Answer (score 0):

What is `SEND_BYTES`? 2? If yes, then `strlen` doesn't work correctly, because the terminating zero is overwritten by `requestHighByte`. Either make `SEND_BYTES` > 2 or use `sizeof(buffer)` to determine number of bytes.

Also you may want to check if result of `write` exactly equals to the amount of data you are sending.